# ajax is sending two variables in google chrome but not sending in mozilla firefox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, firefox

I am trying to send two values through ajax but the problem is that it sends only one value in mozilla

my ajax

```
$('#post_submit').click(function() {
event.preventDefault();
var great_id = $("#post_container_supreme:first").attr("class");
var poster = $("#poster").val() 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "post_update.php",
        data: 'poster='+ poster + '&great_id=' + great_id, //the value in great id is not being sent to the php page
        beforeSend: function() {
            $("#loader_ic").show();
            $('#loader_ic').fadeIn(400).html('<img src="data_cardz_loader.gif" />').fadeIn("slow");
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $("#loader_ic").hide();
            $("#new_post").prepend(data);
            $("#poster").val('');
        }

    })
})
```

})

Comment: Try it  data: {poster:poster,great_id:great_id},                             instead of data: 'poster='+ poster + '&great_id=' + great_id,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few coding errors which may cause the issue. On line 1, you haven't defined the variable `event`, which belongs in the argument-list for the lambda function. Alter to this:

```
$('#post_submit').click(function(event) {
```

Second on line 4, you are missing out a `;` in the end, as well as after the ajax call and on the last line.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing line 8

```
data: 'poster='+ poster + '&great_id=' + great_id, //the value in great id is not being sent to the php page
```

with this:

```
data: {"poster": $("#poster").val(),"great_id": $("#post_container_supreme:first").attr("class")},
```

What I'm doing there is passing an array to the ajax call with your two data element names and values.

Pretty sure you're missing a semi-colon on line 4 as well.

```
var poster = $("#poster").val() ;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `data` parameter of `JQuery.ajax()` <strike>expects</strike> will accept a normal JavaScript object <strike>and not a string</strike>. It will serialize the object and make it a string for you (if it isn't already). This is equivalent (but probably won't help, now that I've learned that your method should work too):

```
var dataToSend = {
    poster: $("#poster").val(),
    great_id: $("#post_container_supreme:first").attr("class")
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "post_update.php",
    data: dataToSend 
    beforeSend: function() {
        $("#loader_ic").show();
        $('#loader_ic').fadeIn(400).html('<img src="data_cardz_loader.gif" />').fadeIn("slow");
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $("#loader_ic").hide();
        $("#new_post").prepend(data);
        $("#poster").val('');
    }
});
```

Comment: A string will work just fine. It all gets converted to a string in the end anyway.

Comment: It expects an object *or* a string, so either are acceptable http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/